# How to check if titleLabel of UIButton exceeds button's frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cgrect

What's the best way to check whether the `titleLabel`'s `text` of a `UIButton` is so long that it actually exceeds the size of the button to prevent situations like the one in the screenshot below? I am used to doing this with `UILabel` and setting the properties `minimumScaleFactor` and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, however when I try to do this with my button it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
self.button.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
self.button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sizeWithAttributes: method in NSString like so

```
NSString *buttonString = @"some string"; // the button's string
    CGSize buttonStringSize = [buttonString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:<button's font family name> size:<the size of the font>]}];
if (buttonStringSize.width == button.bounds.size.witdh){
  // the text of the button is too long for the button's width, do somthing
}
```

Comment: glad to help my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out sizetofit() method.

self.button.frame = // set frame here
self.button.sizetofit()
self.button.frame = CGRect(x:self.button.frame.origin.x, y:self.button.frame.origin.y, width:self.button.frame.width, height: yourStandardHeightVariable) // set the frame again here, this part is done to make sure it doesn't expand too much

disclaimer: this code isn't IDE tested

Comment: sorry, this doesn't really help... :/ calling `sizeToFit` on the button has no effect. also this would actually increase the button size, but what I want is to decrease the font size...

Comment: sorry, i think you should edit the question and make this point more clearer